# MySQL: count how many rows of two tables are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, count, rows, equals

I have two tables, for example:

```
+---------+---------+
| Table A | Table B |
+---------+---------+
|      52 |      12 |
|      64 |       6 |
|      36 |      69 |
|      48 |      52 |
|      12 |         |
+---------+---------+
```

And I want to find how many rows of those tables are the same in one MySQL query.
Any help?

(In our example **2**)

Comment: What is the column name of these table ?

Comment: show us your datatable structures

Comment: Using a simple Inner Join?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)** to find the matching rows between the two tables and then use `COUNT`.

**Query**

```
select count(*) from TableA a
where exists(
    select 1 from TableB b
    where a.col1 = b.col1
);
```

And if you count the unique values,

**Query**

```
select count(distinct *) from TableA a
where exists(
    select 1 from TableB b
    where a.col1 = b.col1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use JOIN statement to counting it:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb1
JOIN tb2 ON tb1.ColumnA = tb2.ColumnA
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `INNER JOIN`**
Let's assume TableA have column A and TableB have column B
So the query will be :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON (A = B);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INNER JOIN`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B on A.col1=B.col1`